# Reinitializing cefsharp with new settings or adding a new cachepath

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have got CefSharp 3 with NuGet, and apparently it initializes as soon as the application starts debugging. My question is, how do I set the cachepath to Cef now that CefSharp 3 starts on its own and doesn't allow manual initialization.

Stopping it and trying to Initalize, isn't allowed neither.

Comment: Please include the exact version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual initialization is allowed and even encouraged. The automatic initialization is only a fallback as lots of new users struggled to get up and running quickly.

Simply call `Cef.Initialize` before you create the first `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance. This call needs to be made on the main application thread (typically the `UI` thread).

See a basic example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms/Program.cs#L15